# Paragraph that takes into account spaces, indentations, etc

Tags: spacing

I have a Paragraph. It begins with \begin{gather*} then for every line there is a \text{...} then \end{gather*}.  I was wondering if there is an easier way to make a Paragraph that takes into account spaces, indentations, etc.

```
 \usepackage{amsmath}
 \usepackage{amsfonts}
 \usepackage{amssymb}
 \begin{document}
 \centering
 \begin{gather*}
 \text{Ecliptic and Equatorial Planes Explained}
 \\
 \text{The distance from the Sun and Earth is iconic.  It is the basic for calculations of other bodies in the solar System and beyond and is the average of the largest and the smallest part of Earth orbit.}
 \\
 \end{gather*}
 \end{document}
```

What are my options for {gather*} so I do not have to write \text for each row and so I get spaces?

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Would you please add a minimal working example of your code and what you are trying to accomplish?  Do you mean that you want spaces and indentation in your source file to appear in the output?  If so, you can try the `verbatim ` environment.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you are after. Can you be a bit more precise? Why would you use `gather*` only to fill it with `\text`?

Comment: Usually, the `gather` and `gather*` environments are used for math material. Your example code contains no math. Is that by design?

Answer (score 3):

An environment such as `gather*` really ought to be used if, and only if, much of the material it contains is math stuff. That doesn't seem to be the case here.

I take it that you want to center-set the text material. (Please advise if this isn't the case...) I can think of two ways your typesetting objective may be achieved:

- Use a `center` environment.

  Plus: very simple

  Minus: material in explanation paragraph can look very "ragged", as no effort is made to (roughly) equalize the line lengths
- Use a `tabularx` environment, with a single column that's set to center its material in such a way that line lengths are roughly balanced.

  Plus: Roughly-balanced material

  Minus: Slightly more work to set up than is required for a `center` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering\arraybackslash}X}
 \begin{document}
\hrule % just to illustrate width of textblock

\begin{center}
Ecliptic and Equatorial Planes Explained

The distance between the Sun and Earth is iconic. It is the basis for 
calculations of other bodies in the solar system and beyond and is 
the average of the largest and the smallest part of Earth orbit.
\end{center}

\medskip\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{C}
Ecliptic and Equatorial Planes Explained\\
The distance between the Sun and Earth is iconic. It is the basis for 
calculations of other bodies in the solar system and beyond and is 
the average of the largest and the smallest part of Earth orbit.
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Which method is "better" for your particular document depends on what you're trying to achieve with the centered layout.

Comment: What if you need to add a \alpha into the tabularx so that it stays on the same line and has text after?

Comment: @er_jack - I'm afraid I don't understand your question. Which line, or lines, are you talking about? Inline math material is easily handled by surrounding it with `$...$`, e.g., by writing `$\alpha$`.